# Date sequencing macro issue with different user

Tags: excel, vba, date

When the command button is checked, the macro creates a unique file everytime by looking into multiple directories and giving a running number. The sequence logic is "YYYY-MM-DD_Running number-NS-userid". The macro is running perfectly in my desktop. But for some users, it is not running properly and I am not able to understand the problem. I have tried changing the code but it seems the problem is in the other user's desktop. For example, when I create a new file, the file will be saved as "2020-11-17_01-NS-cvaa". But for the other user, it is saved as "YYYY-MM-DD01-NS-cvbb". Can someone please help to understand where the issue might be in this case? Any help would be helpful.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim dirPath As String
Dim FileName1, str1, str2, saveFileName As String
Dim MyFile As Variant
Dim MyDirectory As Variant
Dim Counter, FileCounterSrc, FileCounterDst As Long

If CRAcheckbox.Value = False Then
    MsgBox "Confirm SPL check done, Embargo country check done, No Military application "
    End ' stops the macro from running
ElseIf CRAcheckbox.Value = True Then

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("F16:O16,T16:AC16,AD15")) = 0 Or WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("AD9:AM12")) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please select the Requirements of the sheet"
    End ' stops the macro from running

Else
   
Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    
Answer = MsgBox("Please make sure to check/uncheck 'MTDS' checkbox. Are you sure you want to proceed ?", vbYesNo, "Run Macro")
    
If Answer = vbYes Then
 
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim isAlready As Boolean

  Dim LResult As Integer
Dim DirectoryListArray(4) As String
DirectoryListArray(0) = "\\Ad.glpoly.net\main\PCS\"
DirectoryListArray(1) = "\\Ad.glpoly.net\main\PCS\"
DirectoryListArray(2) = "\\Ad.glpoly.net\main\PCS\"
DirectoryListArray(3) = "\\Ad.glpoly.net\main\PCS\"
 Dim DirectoryFilesListArray(2000) As String
 
 'Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 FileName1 = Range("$B$2").Text
 
 If IsNumeric(Mid(FileName1, 12, 2)) = True Then
            FileCounterSrc = Mid(FileName1, 12, 2) + 1
        Else
             str1 = Left(FileName1, 10) & "_01-NS-" & Right(FileName1, Len(FileName1) - 11)
             saveFileName = str1
        End If
 
 
   'Here we are taking 3 folders path in loop
 For Each MyDirectory In DirectoryListArray
    'from each folder we are reading files in loop
    MyFile = Dir$(MyDirectory)
         Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
       
           MyFile = Replace(MyFile, ".xlsm", "")
     
      If Mid(MyFile, 1, 10) = Mid(saveFileName, 1, 10) Then
        If IsNumeric(Mid(saveFileName, 12, 2)) = True Then
              str2 = Mid(saveFileName, 12, 2) + 1
              str2 = Replace(str2, "_", "")
              str2 = IIf(Len(str2) = 1, "0" & str2, str2)
              saveFileName = Left(saveFileName, 10) & "_" & str2 & "-" & Mid(saveFileName, 15, Len(saveFileName) - 1)
                    isAlready = True
               
           'Herer need to save File name by increment sequence with MasterPath
           
          '  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=DirectoryListArray(3) & str1 & ".xlsm", _
           '  FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
            '   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
             '    ActiveWorkbook.Close
               '    break
          End If
         
        End If
       
        MyFile = Dir
       
        Loop
  Next
   
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=DirectoryListArray(3) & saveFileName & ".xlsm", _
             FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
             
Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim emailRng As Range, cl As Range
    Dim sTo As String

    Set emailRng = Worksheets("Database").Range("O2:O6")

    For Each cl In emailRng
        sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value
    Next

    sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = sTo
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " has been issued. "
        .Body = ActiveWorkbook.Name & " has been issued by " & Range("I5").Value
        .Send   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    
               Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                 ActiveWorkbook.Close
                 
   
  'Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(Path)

End If
End If
End If
End Sub
´´´
```

Comment: Try to fully qualify the range in the line `FileName1 = Range("$B$2").Text`. i.e. `FileName1 = thisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetNameHere").Range("$B$2").Text`

Comment: Also what is the formula in `B2`?. Try to avoid using `.Text`. You can alternatively use the formula `=TEXT(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd")` in a different cell (say B3) and in your code use `FileName1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetNameHere").Range("$B$3").Value2`

Comment: Note that in `Dim FileName1, str1, str2, saveFileName As String` only the last variable is of type `String` but the first 3 are of type `Variant`. In VBA you need to declare a type for **every** variable: `Dim FileName1 As String, str1 As String, str2 As String, saveFileName As String`. Same for your other declarations.

Comment: in the cell B2, I have inserted the following formula.
`
=CONCATENATE(TEXT($G$6;"YYYY-MM-DD");"-";$G$5;"-";$G$9;"-";$G$10)
`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors. I implemented these changes and this however has no effect on the outcome of the code. I myself can run this code perfectly fine. However, the other user who is using the same exact file is unable to get the correct outcome. Any suggestions as why is this happening?